# extract month date year into new columns from char column in R

Tags: r, datetime, char, rstudio, lubridate

Hello all and Thank you in advance for your help. I am trying to break down a char column in a df into three separate columns for year, month as (mar) and day. The column I am extracting this from is char data type. Example: "2021-18-02 16:08:48" needs to become
year/month/day as new columns with the separated data.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate`

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(date = "2021-18-02 16:08:48")

data %>% 
  separate(date, into = c("Year","Day","Month","Time"), extra = "merge")

#   Year Day Month     Time
# 1 2021  18    02 16:08:48
```

Comment: Thank you @Mael. I have been trying to figure this out since yesterday. I was trying to use lubridate library ydm() and as.Date()  to break down the column but the formatting was not presenting correctly and All the googling I did did not pull up this easy solution. Maybe I should have slept on it before posting. I am almost ashamed.  Thank you once again for your help